# istioctl command is giving me error "/home/ubuntu/.kube/config" does not exist

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am following up the examples which are part of istio documentation at [IstioSetup](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/quick-start.html)
I am able to install istio as in the documentation but when I try to run istioctl command example `istioctl kube-inject -f samples/bookinfo/kube/bookinfo.yaml`  I get an error as follows

```
**Error: kubernetes configuration file "/home/ubuntu/.kube/config" does not exist**
```

I have installed the kubernetes cluster using kismatic install and have installed it multiple using different version at the end installing Kubernetes 1.9 and with and without ingress . I have tried the same in clustered version and non clustered version giving same error.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `kubectl config view`

Answer (score 0):

Kismatic generates the `kubconfig` file at `generated/kubeconfig` required for `kubectl`.

Either copy this file to `~/.kube/config`, or

use the `--kubeconfig` flag to specify the location of the configuration file when using `kubectl` by doing:

```
kubectl --kubeconfig generated/kubeconfig
```